# How do weighted pressure plates work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do weighted pressure plates work in Minecraft? I know that normal ones(wood and stone) can be activated by walking on them,but how the iron and gold pressure plates work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The golden/iron weighted pressure plates emit a Redstone signal when you drop items on them. A golden weighted pressure plate lets off a full regular pressure plate signal when you drop 60 items onto it. The iron weighted pressure plate emits a full regular pressure plate signal when you drop 600 items on it.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the other because this provides an stackexchange-embedded answer while the other only does Link to the Minecraft wikia